# Show only shell errors inside file

Tags: bash, shell

I want to put all errors inside a file and prevent errors and success messages from printing on the screen. I only want to store the error message.

When I do this like the code below, the errors and success messages are shown on the screen and also inside the `error.out` file.

```
git ls-remote "$GIT_SSH_URL/$REPO.git" 2>&1 > /dev/null | tee error.out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 git ls-remote "$GIT_SSH_URL/$REPO.git" 2>file.log 1>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `2>&1 > /dev/null | tee error.out` part first. [`2>&1` combines the errors and the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean?rq=1), which you don't want, and `tee` prints the input it gets, which you also don't want.

`> /dev/null` suppresses output, and `2> error.out` sends errors to the file.

Comment: Thats works! How can I remove also the success message from the screen?

Comment: And send it where?

Comment: I don't want to store the success message inside a file

Comment: Redirect the whole thing to /dev/null then so ...git" > /dev/null 2>&1